# How to load fast an image URL into android grid view?

Tags: android-asynctask, android-gridview, imageurl

I have this following codes for displaying few url images into my android grid view. the problem is, it takes a lot of time just to display few numbers of images into my grid view. These are my codes:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> galleryAttributes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private int imageWidth;
int ctr = 0;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> galleryAttributes, int imageWidth) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.galleryAttributes = galleryAttributes;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return galleryAttributes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return galleryAttributes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(activity);
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage();

    try {
        Bitmap image = loadImage.execute(galleryAttributes.get(position).get("Link")).get();
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return imageView;   
}


public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(params[0]).getContent(), null, o);
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = imageWidth;
            final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT = imageWidth;
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HEIGHT)
                scale *= 2;
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(params[0]).getContent(), null, o2);
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader  use this for the loading image fast from url in grid list and any other ui you want

Comment: you should use Lazy Loading for showing your url images into your gridview

Comment: how can I do this without using any framework?
can somebody help me how to implement the codes so that the loading of image will not be slow.

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(galleryAttributes.get(position).get("Link")).into(imageView); this line gives me error

Comment: the error stated that : cound not find method com.sqaureup.picasso.Picasso.with, referenced from method "my package here"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use picasso

http://square.github.io/picasso/

This library will cache the picture that downloaded from the URL and next time you open it, it will loaded much more faster because you didn't need to download it again but just take it from the cache.

If the initial displaying is also slow, try to resizing it to reasonable size.

The usage is also pretty easy :

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user Glide or Picasso.
But Glide is having thumbnail support too.

Glide.with(this)
.load(galleryAttributes.get(position).get("Link"))
.thumbnail(0.1f)
.into(imageView);

Picasso.with(this).load(galleryAttributes.get(position).get("Link")).into(imageView);